# I can't sort data in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, angular-material

This is what my component looks like, requests.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DenyReasonRequestFormComponent } from '../deny-reason-request-form/deny-reason-request-form.component'
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ViewComponent } from '../view/view.component';
import { MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { EmpFilter } from  'src/app/models/empfilter';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSelectChange } from '@angular/material/select';
import { HolidayRequestsService } from 'src/app/services/holiday-requests/holiday-requests.service';
import { __core_private_testing_placeholder__ } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HolidayRequests } from 'src/app/models/holiday-requests.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {MatSort, Sort} from '@angular/material/sort';


export interface EmployeeData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-requests',
  templateUrl: './requests.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./requests.component.css'],
  providers: [HolidayRequestsService]
})
export class RequestsComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  _holidayRequests = new MatTableDataSource<HolidayRequests>();
  holidayRequest:HolidayRequests;
   startDate:Date;
   empFilters: EmpFilter[]=[];
   defaultValue = "All";
   filterDictionary= new Map<string,string>();

  public style = "grey"
   public displayedColumns = [
     'name',
     'date',
     'status',
      'view',
  ];

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort : MatSort;

  public DurationOfHolidaysLeave: string[] = ['All', '2021', '2022', '2023']

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
              public http: HttpClient,
    private _holidayRequestsService : HolidayRequestsService,
    ) { }

    view(id:number) {
      const dialogOptions = new MatDialogConfig();
      dialogOptions.disableClose = false;
      dialogOptions.data = {ID:id, parent: this };
      dialogOptions.maxWidth = '45vw';
      dialogOptions.maxHeight = '74vh';
      dialogOptions.height = '100%';
      dialogOptions.width = '100%';
      this.dialog.open(ViewComponent, dialogOptions);
    }


public onApprove(request): void {
    request.Status = 'Approved';
    this.http.put<any>(`http://localhost:1339/holiday-requests/${request.id}`, request)
    .subscribe((res) => {})
  }

public openDialog(request): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DenyReasonRequestFormComponent, {
      data: { request }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        request.Status = 'Denied';
        this.http.put<any>(`http://localhost:1339/holiday-requests/${request.id}`, request)
        .subscribe((res) => {})
      }
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    })
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.empFilters.push({
      name: 'Year', options: this.DurationOfHolidaysLeave,
      defaultValue: this.defaultValue
    });

    this._holidayRequests.sort = this.sort;

    this._holidayRequestsService.getHolidayRequests().subscribe(
      (results)=>
      {
        this._holidayRequests = new MatTableDataSource(results)
        console.log(this._holidayRequests)
        this._holidayRequests.filterPredicate = function (record, filter) {
          var map = new Map(JSON.parse(filter));
          let isMatch = false;
          for (let [key, value] of map) {
            isMatch = (value == "All")
              || (new Date(record['starting_date']).getFullYear() == value
              || (new Date(record['ending_date']).getFullYear() == value));
            if (!isMatch) return false;
          }
          return isMatch;
        }
      }
    );
  }

  applyEmpFilter(ob:MatSelectChange,empfilter:EmpFilter) {
    console.log('applyEmpFilter', this._holidayRequests)
    this.filterDictionary.set(empfilter.name,ob.value);
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(Array.from(this.filterDictionary.entries()));
    this._holidayRequests.filter = jsonString;
  }
}
```

This is what my HTML file looks like

```
<app-breadcumb-toolbar breadcumbPath="New Requests"></app-breadcumb-toolbar>
<div class="container">
    <div class="column column-12">
        <div class="actionToolbar">
            <mat-form-field style="max-width: 150px;" appearance="fill">
                <select matNativeControl required>
                    <option value="TEam1">Team</option>
                    <option value="Team2">Team2</option>
                    <option value="TEam3">TEam3</option>
                    <option value="Team4">Team4</option>
                </select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <!-- <mat-form-field style="margin-left: 30px; max-width: 150px;" appearance="fill">
                <select matNativeControl required>
                    <option value="2022">2022</option>
                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                </select>
            </mat-form-field> -->


            <mat-form-field  style="margin-left: 30px; max-width: 150px;" appearance="fill" *ngFor="let empfilter of empFilters">
                <mat-label>{{ empfilter.name }}</mat-label>
                <mat-select
                  [(value)]="empfilter.defaultValue"
                  (selectionChange)="applyEmpFilter($event, empfilter)"
                >
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let op of empfilter.options" [value]="op">
                    {{ op }}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>



            <mat-form-field style="margin-left: 30px; max-width: 150px;" appearance="fill">
                <select matNativeControl required>
                    <option value="A-Z">Sort</option>
                    <option value="A-Z">A-Z</option>
                    <option value="Z-A">Z-A</option>
                </select>
            </mat-form-field>
            <button class="holiday-approved-button">Approved</button>
            <button class="holiday-denied-button">Denied</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-12">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="_holidayRequests" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" style="text-align: center;">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th style="width: 5%; text-align: center;" mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let request"> {{ request.id }} <!-- {{request.employee.firstName}} {{request.employee.lastName}}  --> </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
                <th style="width: 5%; text-align: center;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Duration of holiday leave
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let request"> {{ request.starting_date }} - {{ request.ending_date }}  </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
                <th style="width: 5%; text-align: center;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let request"
                    [ngStyle]="{'background-color': request.Status=='Denied' ? '#caceca' : (request.Status=='Approved' ? '#c3ffc3' : 'white')}">
                    <div>
                        {{request.Status === "Pending" ? null : request.Status}}
                        <div class="approve-deny-option"
                            [ngStyle]="{'display': request.Status=='Pending' ? 'flex' : 'none'}">
                            <button class="approve-button" (click)="onApprove(request)">A</button>
                            <button class="deny-button" (click)="openDialog(request)">D</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="view">
                <th style="width: 5%" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let request">
                    <button class="add-view-button" mat-button (click)="view(request.id)">View</button>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to sort data from that column with a click of a dropping table, depending on if its a-z to z-a. I have no idea how to do it. I have looked for the tutorials online, but I couldn't figure it out myself.

When A-Z option is selected from mat-form-field, the table should be of course sorted ascending, and the opposite for Z-A.

I'm grateful!

Comment: `this._holidayRequests.sort = this.sort;` is added too soon.  since you are using @ViewChild it will not be ready before `ngAfterViewInit` which is after `ngOnInit`, You could move it into the subscribtion where you set the DataSource.

Comment: Really, if your table is **not** under a *ngIf you can use `@ViewChild(MatSort,{static:true})`. But futhermore you **must** equal this._holidayRequest.sort **after** `this._holidayRequests = new MatTableDataSource(results)` -each time you create a new MatDataTable you need assing again the matSort-